# How to clear Database when you have two dates?

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax

I have a database where i store different informations of a function (name, date when the function was executed, duration, ...)
I have two datepicker where i can choose the date from where the data in my database should be deleted.
How could look like a function where i can delete the data from a specific date to a specific date?

```
//JavaScript
function clearDatabase() {
    console.log('clear database');

    document.getElementById('clearFrom').addEventListener('change', function () {
        var dateFrom = this.value;
        console.log('Clear from: ' + dateFrom);
    });

    document.getElementById('clearTo').addEventListener('change', function () {
        var dateTo = this.value;
        console.log('Clear to: ' + dateTo);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: `/Home/ClearDatabase?from=${dateFrom}&to=${dateTo}`,
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    })
}

//HomeController
[HttpDelete]
public void ClearDatabase(string from, string to)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ClearDatabase");
    //Database name: ChartDatas
}
```

Comment: Which database are you using

Comment: It appears you have a working front-end, which part of the ClearDatabase are you having difficulty with?

Comment: @SaurabhBishnoi Code-First (.mdf)

Comment: I don't know how to clear the database when i have two dates? @freedomn-m